# I am trying to populate sub menu from action but seems like its always saying undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

So, I am using the vakata context menu sub menu and I am trying to create an object containing the item which I would like to display into the sub menu object. As I am calling it in the sub menu, I am always getting undefined instead of the label.

```
return { 
    "AddClient" : {
         label: "Add Client", 
         action: function(itemName){
             var itemName, itemDisp;
             itemName = 'item';
             return itemDisp = {itemName : { label: 'hello'}};
         },                        
         "submenu": {
             itemDisp 
         }
```

so, above I am returning the 'Add Client' as an item it the context menu, then in the action I am creating the var `itemName` which is set to 'item', finally returning the `itemDisp with the item object.

After I'm calling the `itemDisp` in the sub menu. As a result, this should display hello in the context menu sub menu, but instead it is always displaying undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the `itemDisp` variable in your `action` function and set its value in this function so the variable is scoped to this function. If you declared also `itemDisp` globally or at least in an higher scope, just remove the one in the action function.

Your code example is very small and do not allow me to test or reproduce anything so it is hard to help you more.

If you need more help, I encourage you to add more context and make a small piece of code that reproduce your issue (on a service like codesandox, jsbin, etc)